# Unable to load JavaScript in Typescript in Angular 6.0

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I referred numerous articles on stack overflow to invoke JavaScript method in typescript for Angular6, but none of them worked,to begin with am looking for a simple function with an alert to be executed in JavaScript and invoked from typescript, request a working methodology and detailed description of how create the d.ts file for the JavaScript file, and detailed changes in all the configuration files such as angular.json, tsconfig.json etc. , If possible please post a working and tested example for Angular6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to angular.json or angular-cli.json( for angular 4 projects) and add a script tag to reference the external javascript file, lets say demo.js like below

```
"scripts":[
"./assets/demo.js"
]
```

Go to tsconfig.json and add "allowJS" as true like below

```
"allowJS":true
```

add the external js file inside assets folder,lets call it demo.js

under app folder add appcomponent.d.ts for type declaration of the external js file components

create a button in the appcomponent.html that will hit the ts method and call the js method from the javascript.

```
<div>
<button (click)="calljsfunction()"> call external JS file</button>
</div>
```

inside the ts file implement calljsfunction() that will invoke the js method from javascript like below

```
export class AppComponent{

calljsfunction(){
    console.log("inside ts file method");
    var p1 = new Gemoetry.point(1,0)
  }

}
```

implement the d.ts in the app.component.d.ts

```
declare module MGeometry{

export interface Point{
x:number;
y:number;
new (x:number,y:number):Point;
}

export interface Line{
point1:Point;
point2:Point;
new (p1:Point,p2:Point):Point;
}

export interface Main{
 point: Point;
 line : Line;
}
}

declare var Geometry:MGeometry.Main;
```

In demo.js

```
line : (function(){

     function line(p1,p2){

     this.point1 = {x: p1.x, y: p1.y};
     this.point2 = {x: p2.x, y: p2.y};

     }

     return line;

 }  ) (),
```

on similar lines implement the point function in demo.js file

Answer (score 1):

If it is an NPM package like moment is the you can NPM install and a reference it like

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Then use it like any other object

```
moment('dateStringToParse');
```

If you want to add non NPM JavaScript then put the files in your assets folder and include them in your "scripts": [] part of your angular cli json file.

Comment: I said use the scripts section of the of your angular cli json config file, I didn't mention script tags.

Comment: Yes using the script section in angular cli json itself it doesn't work. I am trying to load my own javascript, not from node modules

Answer (score 0):

I think there is so many utility tools to create a scaffolding project template for Angular6. One of the best is angular-cli.

please also make sure that you have node installed in your machine. After node installation then use "npm install -g @angular/cli". For mac/linux please use "sudo" before the command.

After you get the confirmation, create a directory where your project files will live and then "cd" into the directory. Type "ng new ". This will take few minutes to load all the dependencies along with the configuration of "TypeScript" and "WebPack". Angular cli will hide the configuration of webpack file but it uses this when you are building project.

Then finally use "ng serve" to see if angular is properly running.

The advantage of angular cli is that it imposes best practices when you are developing the code. I used this in one of my SharePoint project to build shopping cart and liked it very much.

You can also see the official documentation by clicking on below link:
https://cli.angular.io/

Happy coding!!

Comment: I already know how to create Angular6 project Tanuj, please re read the problem statement